# What's the difference between continueWith() and onSuccess() in Bolts framework?

Tags: android, bolts-framework

I am using [Bolts framework](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android) in my Android project. I read the documents several times, but I am still confused about the difference between continueWith() and onSuccess(), because the callback method and the return value are all the same. For example,

```
Task task = ParseGeoPoint.getCurrentLocationInBackground(10*1000);
```

And what's the difference between these two methods?

```
task.onSuccess(new Continuation<ParseGeoPoint, Object>() {
    @Override
    public Object then(Task<ParseGeoPoint> task) throws Exception {
        Log.d(TAG, "task done");
        return null;
    }
});

task.continueWith(new Continuation<ParseGeoPoint, Object>() {
    @Override
    public Object then(Task<ParseGeoPoint> task) throws Exception {
        Log.d(TAG, "task done");
        return null;
    }
});
```

Comment: can you pls description me how to use Bolts framework? I am new in android developing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, `onSuccess()` is just called, as its name indicates, when the call completes without errors. On the other hand, `continueWith()` is called always, even in case of failure. Therefore, use `onSuccess()` when you are interested only in retrieve the result on successful requests, and use `continueWith()` if you want also be able to handle failed requests.

Comment: Can you please help me out with integrating bolts. I have had a look at the git link but since I'm not well-versed in droid, I cant seem to create a task in the first place. I have absolutely no idea how to use bolts in my app but I want to cause I have a lot of uploading threads that has to be done asynchronously. Any guidance or any tutorial that you know of ?